# How to check whether a src file or spec has been loaded by karma or not?

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

I am running karma test runner for jasmine test suites. I am not sure whether my source and spec files are being loaded are not. How to check whether a src file or spec has been loaded by karma or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run your karma test using Chrome Browser.
In that case, you can check the files loaded by karma using the source tab under the Chrome Dev tools.

You can also check the logs and debug your scripts as well.

Comment: thanks for the help but I am using grunt-karma package